# how do I find a value given in firebase that is one of several attributes?

Tags: objective-c, firebase

****UPDATED****

here is the firebase layout

```
"Recent" : {     
"-KCF2_4VmCXn38fbJ07h" : {
          "counter" : 15,
          "date" : "2016-03-07T17:44:58",
          "description" : "Master",
          "groupId" : "7Z7hoKapTS",
          "lastMessage" : "AwGABL7h0ZPkXCuKvyu7PF6jcmClkdAT3AgaKkBPkBaA460cexzvpoTqfNSvn+5lILB4++AKBufHmdOIVS1giJ8EeV0V+2Dd6UlGqRvOPNQNvg==",
          "members" : [ "mf1Q6ogUHD", "mf1Q6ogUHD", "mf1Q6ogUHD", "MvKHg4Hh3L" ],
          "password" : "JHttZvN9Uw",
          "profileId" : "MvKHg4Hh3L",
          "recentId" : "-KCF2_4VmCXn38fbJ07h",
          "type" : "group",
          "userId" : "mf1Q6ogUHD"
        }
}
```

Here is my updated query! I am now retrieving my array from firebase and putting it in an NSMutable array! Now all I need to do is delete the value of `members` (which I do not know how to do yet) and then write in the new array!

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
NSString *nsUser = (NSString *)user;
NSMutableArray *recentIds;
NSMutableArray *members;

Firebase *firebase = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Recent", FIREBASE]];
FQuery *query = [[firebase queryOrderedByChild:@"groupId"] queryEqualToValue:group.objectId];
    [query observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        [recentIds addObject:snapshot.value[@"recentId"]];
        [members addObjectsFromArray:snapshot.value[@"members"]];
         NSLog(@"RecentId: %@", snapshot.value[@"recentId"]);
    }];
      for(id member in members) {
            if([member isEqual:nsUser]) {
                [members removeObject:member];
                break;
            }
        }

        for(id recentId in recentIds){
            Firebase *firebase2 = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/members", recentId, @"%@/Recent/", @"https://gibber.firebaseio.com/"]];
            [firebase2 setValue: members];
        }
for(id member in members) {
    NSLog(@"Members: %@", member);
}
```

And then the loop at the end is to loop through the different Recent nodes that were stored in the array and place the member array as the value of the member node at that location

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. Same for the screenshot of a table. Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: gotcha! one minute! I didnt realize that I could do that!

Comment: Aside from that: which code does the actual update to your Firebase database? Is it in `UpdateRecentItem()`. If so, you probably should add the code for that too.

Comment: I updated my query to where I am at now. I am pretty close, But I think I have something going on that is breaking it

Comment: I also do not understand why outputting to console snapshot.value[@"members"]; gives me a null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this statement may answer the question:

From the Firebase website (this is one of the requirements if you use arrays in Firebase)

> To remove keys, we save the entire array instead of using removeValue

You may want to consider an alternate  Firebase data structure; if you are going to be working with the data on a specific level (adding, editing, removing). Array's may not be the best solution. Something like the following example will provide far more flexibility.

In your members parent node, have child nodes with the user id as the key, and true as the value. You can then remove any one user node.

```
   members
        pQJlYrHbq2: true
        BC8MRaq7Zl: true
        PxOJQe8BdD: true
        MvKHg4Hh3L: true

Firebase *ref = [userRef childByAppendingPath(@"members");
Firebase *memberToRemove = [ref childByAppendingPath("PxOJQe8BdD")

[memberToRemove removeValue]
```

If you have not done so, check out this fabulous blog from Firebase about arrays:

[Array's in Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Edit: based on additional info from the OP, I thought it may be good to add code to read the array, manipulate it and write it back out. This code is very verbose and should be clear enough to follow.

```
Firebase *ref = [self.myRootRef childByAppendingPath:@"Recent"];

    FQuery *query = [[ref queryOrderedByChild:@"groupId"] queryEqualToValue:@"Pkmwa3WUrH"];

    [query observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

        NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;

        NSString *counter = [dict valueForKey:@"counter"]; //do something with
        NSString *groupId = [dict valueForKey:@"groupId"]; //counter and the groupId
        NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict valueForKey:@"members"]];

        [mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];//remove the object at index 1

        //now build a path to write the array back out to
        NSString *nodeKey = snapshot.key;
        Firebase *path = [ref childByAppendingPath:nodeKey];
        Firebase *specificPath = [path childByAppendingPath:@"members"];

        [specificPath setValue:mutableArray]; //write the array back out

    }];
```

Comment: Ah, that helps some, but the keys to member are 0..*  I need to check the value of members children and then remove the key where the value is the id that I am looking for... Also, how do I append my query to go all the way to member? Instead of just to the message... My code wasn't even letting me put snapshot.members in the log

Comment: where I am stuck is that I dont have the key, but I do have the value...I need to know how I would look at member and remove the item from ti that == me

Comment: What you are saying is the value you have is the item you want to be able to remove. As I demonstrated above, change your logic: make the value the key and the value equals true. So it would be a key:value pair of PxOJQe8BdD: true. If you do that you can avoid the array and the query entirely. If you really want to query, use the same structure I presented and do a [Deep Query](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html) to find the node you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, and I don't think snapshot.value[@"members"]); is valid. Not sure what you were expecting. The snapshot contains key:value pairs so snapshot.value returns whatever the value is; which could be a dictionary that has key:value pairs or other Firebase defined types.

Comment: ah okay, so i need to take my query deeper...I am not so good at firebase yet, and that Is a part that I am struggling at, so i need the snapshot to be members to do this?

Comment: There's a members node already within your snapshot (per your question). You can go deeper, but you really need to avoid using arrays so the first step would be to change your structure to make it more manageable. Then you can look into deep queries.

Comment: so How do I remove my objectId from snapshot[@"members"]

Comment: Please review my answer: it provides an answer to your question, and also shows a better way to structure your data and also a small code example of how to remove a child of the members node with that better structure.

Comment: The problem though is that my project already consists of around 7000 lines of code and to go back and restructure that is not really an option...I have to remove an item from the array.

Comment: Then the answer is what is stated by the Firebase requirements of using an array:  *To remove keys, we save the entire array instead of using removeValue*. You cannot remove an element from the array, you have to read it in, manipulate the data and then write the whole array back out.

Comment: Am I referencing a snapshots reference correctly, for instance snapshot.value[@"members"] being the array of members? Xcode is giving me errors on it

Comment: as to the reading the whole array and writing it back, that might be the best solution, this action isnt going to be a super active function of my app

Comment: they use   NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value[@"author"]);
  NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value[@"title"]);
}]; In their example on firebase.com so I dont know why that isnt working for me

Comment: I got it reading my array in! Now All I need to do is record the new array back in...